# 3-Connected Planar Graphs and Cycles

Tags: graph-theory, planar-graphs

**Some definitions:**

> $\textbf{$k$-connected}$: $G = (V, E)$ is called $k$-connected (for $k
> > \in \mathbb{N}$) if $|G| > k$ and $G-X$ is connected for every set
> $X \subseteq V$ with $|X| < k$.

**Facts**:

- If a graph is $3$-connected it is also $2$-connected
- In $2$-connected plane graph, every face is bounded by a cycle.

> $\textbf{Theorem 1:}$ Show that if $u$ is a vertex in a $3$-connected planar graph, there is
> a cycle of the graph that contains the neighbors of $u$.

I was wondering if I can solve **Theorem 1** using the **Facts** I described above. If so, I would like to know how I could argue. Or if there is any other way to show it

Comment: I have a guess. Let's let $e_0, \ldots, e_{k-1}$ be the edges in $v$, arranged in clockwise order. There are faces $F_i$ that contain edges $e_i, e_{i+1 \mod k}$, for $i = 0, \ldots k-1$. Try XORing all of these cycles $C_i$ corresponding to those faces.

Comment: @LorenzoNajt While this does work, it's not that easy to see why this works if $G$ is 3-connected, but doesn't work if $G$ is 2-connected, which is one (very minor) drawback of this proof strategy.

Comment: @BrandonduPreez If I'm not mistaken, the argument can be completed by observing that if any of the C_i intersect in the wrong places, removing v and one of those intersection points will disconnect the graph. This seems reasonable after some doodles, but sees tedious to argue formally. I like the argument you suggest more. :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, those facts suffice to prove Theorem 1.

Here's a hint:

> If $G$ is 3-connected, then $G-u$ is 2-connected.

And some more:

> Further, the vertex $u$ lies in a face $f$ of $G-u$ in the plane, and every neighbor of $u$ has to lie on the cycle bounding $f$ by planarity.

Answer (score 1):

If I understand your question correctly, it might be preety straightfoward. Let me give you an idea:

Let $G$ be your 3-connected planar graph and let $v\in V(G)$. As you mentioned we have that
$G$ is also 2-connected, which by Menger's Theorem gives us that there exist at least two independent paths between any two vertices of $G$. Obviously, this fact implies the existence of circuits containing $v$.

Let $C$ be a maximal circuit on $G$ containing $v$ and assume that there exists $w\in \text{Adj}(v)$ such that $w\not\in C$. In this case, we consider the 'last' vertex $u$
of $C$ and paths $P_1$ from $u$ to $w$ and $P_2$ from $w$ to $v$. Appending $P_1$ and
$P_2$ to $C$, we obtain another circuit $\overline{C}$ which contains $C$. This contradicts our assumption that $C$ was maximal.

Try out checking the details!

**P.S:** I didn't see the relation of your proposition with planarity

Comment: What's the 'last' vertex of C?

Comment: I don't know if you are considering your graph is oriented. If not, any of the vertices of $C$ which are adjacent to $v$ in $C$

Comment: The graphs are undirected. You can take $P_2 = \{w,v\}$, how do you guarantee that $P_1$ only intersects $C$ at $u$?

Comment: I think $P_1$ intersecting $C$ is a place where this can break -- not saying it does, for sure, but just that there a potential issue here. For instance, the first intersection of $P_1$ with $C$ could be much farther away in $C$ from $v$, and then interchanging that part of $C$ with $P_1$ won't increase the length of the cycle.

Comment: Ene potential place of miscommunication: I think the question is asking about  cycles / simple circuits, not circuits. There are no cycles that contain other cycles.

Comment: You're right about your concerns. Anyway, note that if we take $P_2$ as you said this problem doesn't appear. Moreover, although it's more complicated I'm quite sure we can manage the intersections of $P_1$. I'll give it a try.